# Vivo phones runtime-error on inflating layout

Tags: android, imageview, runtime-error

I'm experiencing the following run-time crash almost exclusively on Vivo devices (99%):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx/com.xxx.android.mainpresenter.screens.home.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class ImageView
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity + 2953(ActivityThread.java:2953)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity + 3031(ActivityThread.java:3031)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1732(ActivityThread.java:1732)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 192(Looper.java:192)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6792(ActivityThread.java:6792)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 438(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 826(ZygoteInit.java:826)
```

this is the imageview in question

```
<!-- placeholder image -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/placeholder_iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/default_image_description"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder_xxx" (This is a JPG)
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

I've earlier had luck with including the image used in the ImageView into the into a noDpi folder. But this time (it's the second occurrence) the app has an image in a noDpi folder, but this crash occurs.

I would be grateful for any tip, hunch or of course a solution.

Comment: is "placeholder_xxx" a vector drawable?

Comment: the image is a JPG.

Answer (score 0):

If your @drawable/placeholder_xxx is a vector drawable then you need to change the property from android:src="@drawable/placeholder_xxx" to app:srcCompat="@drawable/placeholder_xxx" and add xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" in your container layout which you are using.